# Nodejs best practice for setting environment variables

Tags: node.js

In nodejs, it's common to set

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development' // or 'production'
```

This helps dead code elimination, such as when using Uglifyjs, webpack

What about for testing, for targeting browser, or server etc?

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test' // is this good?
process.env.TEST = true // or is this better?

process.env.APP_ENV = 'browser' // browser specific codes when building "universal" app
process.env.APP_ENV = 'server' // server specific codes
process.env.APP_ENV = 'node' // or this for server
process.env.BROWSER = true // or this
process.env.SERVER = true //
```

I can think of these:

Using `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'`

- Simple, only 1 env variable to set
- But may break other third parties' tool, such as babel, which requires either `development` or `production`

Using `process.env.TEST = true`

- Doesn't interfere with `NODE_ENV`
- But more env variables to set and remember (mental load), need to set DefinePlugin (such as when using webpack)
- Again, some other third parties may have use `process.env.TEST = somethingElse`

What are other pros and cons of these approaches and are there existing "best practices"?

Comment: What do you want a `test` variable for? I'd argue **this is not something you ever want in your server code**, unless you want it to work on test and break on prod. Now if you're refering to build/dataset/configuration, then it's ok to separate test from prod.